# How to update column with case statement and typecast?

Tags: sql, sql-update, case

I have tried the below but it gives this error

```
ERROR:  column "rating" is of type numeric but expression is of type text
LINE 2: set rating = CASE                     ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

```sql
    update rating  
    set cast rating as varchar = CASE 
    WHEN rating<0 THEN '0'  
    When rating>3.5 THEN '4'  
    When rating is null THEN '-1'    
    End
```

Comment: error says it all, rating is numeric , so get rid of the quotes around your numbers

Comment: _"Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL. "_

Answer (score 0):

have you tried explicitely casting the text as numeric ?

```
update rating  
set cast rating as varchar = CASE 
WHEN rating<0 THEN '0'::numeric
When rating>3.5 THEN '4'::numeric
When rating is null THEN '-1'::numeric
End
```

Comment: It would be simpler to just use `0` instead of `'0'`, etc. Also, are you sure the OP is using PostgreSQL?